# How to know dependencies of 3rd party aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, aar

I'm trying to generate signed APK with Android Studio 3.0.1. Debug build seems to work ok but I'm getting an error with release build:

> Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes

I am using a 3rd party AAR file and when I unzip it I can see that it has `support-annotations-23.0.1.jar` in libs folder.

Questions:

1. Has 3rd party AAR creator used jar instead of dependency? Or does Android Studio include dependency libraries as jars when it builds AAR.
2. Is there a way to look dependencies of AAR file

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to look dependencies of AAR file

The aar file doesn't contain the transitive dependencies and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.
It means that there isn't am automatic way to check the dependencies and the only way is to unzip the file and check manually the files inside to find jars and other class files.